# Excel Macro to Auto Generate ID using current Month, Year and number

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create auto generated string once I click on Add button.
String consists of current Year,Month and sequence.
yymm##=140501
where ## represents the number for that month. 
If I click on 'Add' again in same month then 140502.
So the last 2 number is incrementing followed by 140503, 140504, 140505...

For Next Month, when I click on 'Add' it should come with 140601, 140602
For new month, the last 2 number count reset to 1.
I have tried a little:

```
Sub AutoID()
Dim autoid1 As String
Dim intLastRow As Long

For i = 1 To 100
autoid1 = "FT" & Format(Date, "yymm") & i

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to stire the current sequence number somewhere: either in a hidden sheet or (eg) in a workbook name (where the name's "name" is yymm and the "value" is the current/next sequence number.

Comment: Please tell me how you generate the numbers - is it all in one go, or do you need to have a generator other people can open and use? Is it that you have a list of reports and dates, and want to generate an id for each, or do reports come in dynamically, and you need to preserve the last value when the workbook is closed? If so, just write the most recent value to cell A1 of an `xlVeryHidden` data sheet every time the function is called, and write the month that number was generated in into B1. Then you can just check first whether it's a new month, and then either reset or add

Answer (score 0):

This will create the number you're asking for, but it will lose it's ability to remember the last number for that month, or whether it's a new month, once the static variables are de-scoped

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print NewID
Next i

End Sub


Public Function NewID() As String

Dim m As String, y As String
Static inclNum As Integer
Static lastMonth As Integer

inclNum = inclNum + 1
m = Format(Date, "mm")
y = Format(Date, "yy")

If lastMonth = 0 Then lastMonth = CInt(m)

If CInt(m) <> lastMonth Then
    lastMonth = CInt(m)
    inclNum = 1
End If

NewID = CStr(inclNum)

If Len(NewID) < 2 Then NewID = "0" & NewID

NewID = y & m & NewID


End Function
```